# Не понимаю, что от меня хотят, как это работает) (c++)

Tags: c++, олимпиада

[image: Условие]

[image: input/output]

Задача A. Распознавание деталей

Ваша задача - написать программу для распознавания деталей заданного вида на конвейере. Изображение нужной детали вводится при начале распознавания. Далее вводится изображение части конвейера, на котором могут находиться детали различных видов. Требуется распознать и выделить все изображения заданной детали.

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю, что вы от нас хотите

Comment: Найдите все отражения картинки среди буковок и поменяйте регистр буковок, там, где нашли)

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2):

от вас хотят, чтобы в матрице 20x10 вы смогли найти изображения и выделить их переведя маленькие буквы в большие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути вам надо проверить что фигура, образованная одинаковыми буквами при вращении является той же фигурой, что и заданной вначале

Comment: Это я понял) я теперь голову ломаю как все 4 расположения изображения записать, учитывая что ввод у меня идет не в string массив, а построчно (5 строк) в общем работы еще много. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Danila Pustovoyt, ну и что что идет построчно? что мешает первые 5 строк записать в список? вообще если не требуется совсем уж оптимальное решение, то задача нормально решается и в лоб - из массива 5x5 надо сделать 8 массивов (4 поворота и отражение) и дальше бегать по матрице 20x10 и сравнивать (со своей спецификой конечно)